# Given an ID find which table the element belongs to an retrieve the data

Tags: mysql, sql

I am building a discord archival bot. I have a `channels` table that references 6 other channel types. I think I have managed to insert the data properly, but I am not confident as to how I can retrieve it. I have a `types` field in the `channels` but that requires 2 queries to get the data back and I don't think it's possible to do with SQL without using if statements. I was wondering if it's possible to do it in a single query or if there are any improvements to the schema that I can make.

> Each ID is unique across all 6 types if that helps.

EDIT: For example I want to get all the data for a channel with an ID: 1.

I have to `SELECT * FROM channels WHERE ID = 1` and then

```js
if (types === "text")

else if (types === "voice") etc...
```

`SELECT * FROM channel_${channel_type_here} WHERE ID = 1`

Is it possible to somehow reduce this to 1 query.

EDIT2: As per [davidp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6896061/davidp)
suggestion this is what i came up with this SQL query

```
SET @channels := "SELECT types FROM channels WHERE channel_id = '365539086456586240' INTO @types"; 

PREPARE dynamic_statement FROM @channels;
EXECUTE dynamic_statement;

SET @dynamic_channels = CONCAT(CONCAT('SELECT * FROM channel_',@types), " WHERE channel_id = '365539086456586240'");

PREPARE dynamic_statement FROM @dynamic_channels;
EXECUTE dynamic_statement;

DEALLOCATE PREPARE dynamic_statement;
```

It selects the correct channel and table given some ID and everything is done in a single query. MySQL reports 0.003s execution so it's definetly within the margin of error, but the table is quite small so I can't tell how well it scales but it's very good for now.

If anyone has some other suggestion even if it includes changing the schema I would be very thankfull, otherwise the question can be considered as answered

[image: Relationships visualized]

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking for. What data are you trying to retrieve? What 2 queries does it require? Tell us what you've already tried and check out the [mre] help page.

Comment: I see at least 4 tables with virtually identical structures so should really be 1 table with another field to identify group (voice, store, news, category). Might even include 5th table as a group (text).

Comment: And now I think 6th table (dm) should be another group. Yes, there could be empty fields for some records but will greatly simplify search and filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to dynamically choose which table to query the data from based on the result of querying the first table. Without using if statements or changing the database structure, you'd probably need to use [dynamic SQL](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2014/06/20/mysql-dynamic-sql-with-execute-and-prepare-statements/) to build that second query.